# textview of listview in android

Tags: android, listview, textview

I have Listview that contains a Textview, I populate data from sqlite inside them , now I want to change the textview background color for each row based on the value in each one.

I couldn't do it , can anybody help me for how to get each textview from the listview ??

Edit :
Here is my code to populate the listview:

```
  sql = new SqlCommands(getApplicationContext());
Fields = new String[]{SqlCommands.Group, SqlCommands.Subject, SqlCommands.Body, SqlCommands.DateTime};
int [] Dview = new int []{R.id.grop, R.id.sbj,R.id.bdy,R.id.DT};
Cursor c = sql.GetData();
Adpt = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.items, c , Fields, Dview ,0 );
NotiLst.setAdapter(Adpt);
```

this is the XML file for the items :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    android:background="@drawable/grp_shap" >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/Prio"   
            android:layout_width="32dip"
            android:layout_height="32dip"
            />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grop"
        android:layout_width="64sp"
        android:layout_height="40sp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Prio"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

        android:text="S"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/DT"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="14sp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/title"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Date  Rec"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:textSize="12sp"

         />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bdy"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="28sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/DT"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/hi"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Prio"
    android:text="Body"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sbj"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="12sp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bdy"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/bdy"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:text="Subject"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/hi"
    android:layout_width="20dip"
    android:layout_height="26dip"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/DT"
    android:layout_below="@+id/DT"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:src="@drawable/highprio" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and I have a listview on the activity_mail layout which populated whith this items.
I want to change the color for the textview with id grop based on the value inserted on it

Comment: Show your code, layouts, adapters, all you have for your list

Comment: Usually it is very easy to do in your adapter but it depends on layout also.

Comment: Read this article: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Implementing-a-Heterogenous-ListView

Comment: @shadox I add them in the post

Answer (score 1):

> You should use a custom adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static class ViewHolder {
        public final TextView mTv;
    }

    private final Context mContext;
    private final List<String> mList; //you can change this to String array

    public MyAdapter (Context context, List<String> list) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mList= list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder h;
        final String string = mList.get(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.item_listview, null);
            h = new ViewHolder();
            h.mTv= (TextView) convertView .findViewById(R.id.mTvRes);
            convertView.setTag(h);
        } else {
            h = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        h.mTv.setText....
        h.mTv.setTextColor....
        h.mTv.setBackground....

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

in your activity:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(Fields);
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, list);
NotiLst.setAdapter(adapter);
```

> I didn't checked it and you maybe need to do some changes but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.label = (TextView)  convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        viewHolder.label.setBackground(getResources().getColor(color.white));
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    viewHolder.label.setText(activitiesList.get(position).getName());
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: You could extend your cursor adapter. I'm not using CursorAdapters usually so search for some information on Google on how to extend it.